# JavaScript: How to get height of image after change the src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <img/>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $(".btn").click(function() {
  $(".modal img").prop("src", "new src");
  alert($(".modal img").height());
  $(".modal").modal("show");
 });
```

Alert: `0`

Hello, I am trying get height of image after change the src.
i have a image in the bootstrap modal, after click the button change src of the image and show the modal .
I can not get correct height of image, because the image wont loaded src until modal is visible, So any way to force the src to load, or any way to get the correct height.BTW i tried `onload` and `load`, both not work.

Comment: you need to make an additional new Image(), and wait for that to load. Once loaded, get the specs and set the src to the newly loaded image.

Comment: `.onload` or jQuery's `.load` should be the way to go. Show those attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/yyma7fkj/

```
    $(".btn").click(function() {
  $(".modal img").load(function() {
    alert("height:" + this.height + " width:" + this.width);
    $(".modal").modal("show");
  }).prop("src", "http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png");
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried in jsfiddle, still not work
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1nqz5xz/5/)

Comment: I updated the code. i meant to do this.height instead of $(this).height()

Comment: Thanks again, it is great, solve my problem.

PS this.height looks like the original height of image. But not the height recalculated by CSS.

Comment: glad I could help. Mark this as the answer if it solves your problem